# HAXm not installing: Error while waiting for device: Could not start AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, haxm

I'm new to android development and I installed android studio but any time I try to run the emulator it says "HAXM was not installed" and when I install it, it says done but when I try to run it, it says "HAXM was not installed" again. If I try ignoring the error, it says "Error while waiting for device: Could not start AVD".

I've tried several solutions online like Installing it from SDK manager, turning on virtualization but none of them worked